# Use CMake binares to build cpp projects without installing CMake

Tags: cmake, cmake-modules

I want to use specific version of CMake 3.19.0 for Ubuntu 14.04 (32-bits) without installing CMake (use only binaries).

I tried to build CMake 3.19.0 on my test machine. It builded and installed successfully. In `install_manifest.txt` I see lot of files that were installed on my test system.

So, I tried to copy only installed binaries from `/usr/local/bin/` (this is default path where CMake binaries were installed) and paste it to another machine that doesn't know about CMake. I paste 3 binaries: `cmake, ctest, cpack` to `/usr/local/bin/`.

If I run `which cmake` it shows path:

```
/usr/local/bin/cmake
```

If I run `cmake --verison` it shows:

```
CMake Error: Could not find CMAKE_ROOT !!!
CMake has most likely not been installed correctly.
Modules directory not found in
/usr/local/share/cmake-3.19
cmake version 3.19.0

CMake suite maintained and supported by Kitware (kitware.com/cmake).
```

It looks like CMake needs some modules that I haven't copied yet. I tried to build my cpp project and it shows me:

```
CMake Error: Could not find CMAKE_ROOT !!!
CMake has most likely not been installed correctly.
Modules directory not found in
/usr/local/share/cmake-3.19
CMake Error: Error executing cmake::LoadCache(). Aborting.
```

What are the minimum required modules needed for stable building? And where I should copy it?

Comment: "It looks like CMake needs some modules that I haven't copied yet." - Yes, it is true: CMake uses modules which are contained in separate files. "What are the minimum required modules needed for stable building?" - It depends on which project you are building and with which options. You could run building your project under `strace` and check which module files are opened during that building.

Comment: Is this an academic question, or are you trying to solve a specific problem?

Comment: @StephenNewell specific problem. Problem solved below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just copied builded Modules and Templates directories from `cmake-3.19.0` build directory to `/usr/local/share/cmake-3.19`